# Persistent data structures in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, open-source, persistence

I need a persistent storage in Java for certain (possibly large) data structures, such as:

- dense and sparse matrices of integers, doubles, booleans
- directed graphs with labeled nodes and edges
- binary trees
- maps: string->string, string->integer (with fast retrieval of the keys with largest values)
- sets of integers or strings

I don't mind if there is a separate storage for each data structure, as long as all the storages have similar, consistent interfaces.

I need to be able to efficiently modify the data structures "remotely", that is, without fetching the entire structure to RAM, modifying it, and storing back.  Example operations: put a key-value in a map, remove a node from a tree, modify a node's label in a graph, add a value to a set.

It would be very nice if these storages could be also easily accessed from other programming languages, most notably Python.  I'm thinking of a RESTful service in the backend and client APIs in Java and Python.

Motivation: I need to process a large collection of documents and perform various analyses on them.  I want to explore various approaches and create fast prototypes (for that reason I need simple, easy-to-use APIs).

I guess I'm not the first person needing such a functionality and I would hate to reinvent the wheel here.  Which brings me to the question: **which open-source solutions allow easy-to-use persistence of data structures in Java?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about using something like [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB)? It seem perfect for what your looking for and Its picking up a lot of steam.   It's a high-performance, schema-free document-oriented database and I love the fact it's based on json!  Check it out!

[Here](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/816470307/tutorial-mongodb-in-java#using_mongodb_java_driver_api) is nice Java tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, it's an interesting idea.  I'm thinking about using MongoDB or another NoSQL solution as a "low-level" backend for some of the stores (maps and sets for sure).  However, I also need a consistent Java API for CRUD operations on the data-structures, and I'm hoping that someone has already did that.

Comment: hmmm interesting.  I haven't mixed JPA and MongoDB together yet.  Seems like a un-likely pair.  However; there are a couple tutorials on the net about MongoDB and java.

Answer (score 0):

How about ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream?

Comment: Thanks, but that is too generic, and does not allow data structure-specific modifications without fetching the entire object.  Example: I have a stored tree with 10M nodes, I want to add a leaf.  I don't want to fetch and deserialize the entire tree, modify it, serialize and store it.  The entire tree may not fit in memory.  What I want to do is modify the persisted tree.

Comment: He mention that he don't want load all the data to change something

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to wire all that but you can use JPA with bi-directional mappings and lazy-loading.

Answer (score 0):

It would really depend on you usage patterens, i.e., how many reads, how many writes, how often, etc, but I would suggest you just use sql until you prove that it will not work.